# Laravel 5.2 Login of a user

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.2 and have some trouble with the login of the user:

```
$email = $request->input('email');
$password = $request->input('password');

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
}
```

Problem: 
The following code return the email of the current user:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    return Auth::user()->email;
}
```

When instead, in the redirected admin blade template I use: Auth::user()->email I get a "Error Exception" - Trying to get property of non-object. The Auth::check() method return false.

I read in the documentation that only routes places inside

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```

have access to the session. So I put the admin/dashboard route within this route group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Now I get the following error: Container.php line 702: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! Any ideas why this happen?
Thank you

Comment: It could be possible because of a loop. Your route says /admin/dashboard goes to the index method of your Admin Controller. However, in your index method (I think) you are trying to authenticate the user, and if it's successful you're redirecting them to the admin/dashboard - and so the process continues.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});
```

all of routes in laravel 5.2 goes inside web middleware ;
see this Q? : 
[Laravel 5.2 routes with web midellware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37037388/laravel-5-2-routes-with-web-midellware/37037524#37037524)

---

never change xdebug.max_nesting_level
if nesting_level reached 100 nesting that tells you there is a problem with usage of midellware or anything like that

Answer (score -1):

this is happening for xdebug.To solve go to your php.ini file and put this line

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

make nesting level more than 100 or whatever you want.If you want anonymous nesting level use

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = -1
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I add xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200 or  xdebug.max_nesting_level = -1. Any ideas why? I restared wamp already. Thank you