# Laravel 5.2 routes with web midellware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with `[Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {}); ]`
when I use it in the routes file it shows this error:

```
FatalErrorException in Container.php line 702:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

my routes.php is :

```
use App\Discussion;
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

        Route::get('/', function () {

            return view('welcome');
        });
        Route::auth();
    });

        Route::get('home', function () {
            $discussion = Discussion::orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get();

            return view('home', [
                'discussions' => $discussion,

        ]);
});
```

and this is the homeController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Discussion;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
    }
}
```

this is the error :

```
FatalErrorException in Container.php line 702:
Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
in Container.php line 702
at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 133
at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 118
at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
at Container->normalize() in Container.php line 179
at Container->bind() in Container.php line 1199
at Container->offsetSet() in Container.php line 39
at AuthServiceProvider->Illuminate\Auth\{closure}() in Container.php line 735
at Container->build() in Container.php line 633
at Container->make() in Application.php line 697
at Application->make() in Container.php line 1178
at Container->offsetGet() in Facade.php line 151
at Facade::resolveFacadeInstance() in Facade.php line 120
at Facade::getFacadeRoot() in Facade.php line 207
at Facade::__callStatic() in f6edb10b0490bd0fe5a2fb364a623ddb1e0231d4.php line 56
at Auth::guest() in f6edb10b0490bd0fe5a2fb364a623ddb1e0231d4.php line 56
in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath() in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get() in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in aa3aed20f72e2364ebd8d243052a41cdb52d5295.php line 17
in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath() in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get() in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent() in Response.php line 199
at Response->__construct() in Router.php line 1087
at Router->prepareResponse() in Router.php line 725
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack() in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute() in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch() in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:52}() in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle() in Pipeline.php line 136
at call_user_func_array:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:136}() in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline.php:32}() in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at call_user_func:{C:\wamp\www\social\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php:103}() in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then() in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter() in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle() in index.php line 54
in server.php line 21
at {main}() in server.php line 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Laravel 5.2, all routes are wrapped with the `Web Middleware`, so there is no reason to define `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']);` anymore.

In RouteServiceProvider:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

Which is instantiated by a previous function in the same file:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);

    //
}
```

Which is called by the `Kernel` stack.

This should solve the nesting issue.

Comment: now when i try to access /home which needs user login to access , it access it and throw an errors even im not loged in